# Create Outlook appointment in subfolder/subcalendar with python

Tags: python, outlook, calendar, createitem

searched all entries on the topic and I am close to solution but help is appreciated:
I want to create calendar entries in a non-default calendar in Outlook via python. I did

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace('MAPI')
calendar = outlook.Folders('myaccount@mail.com').Folders('calendar').Folders('subcalendar')
```

I can read entries, count entries of the subcalendar - all good.
Now I try to create a new item in this 'subcalendar' by

```
newapp = calendar.CreateItem(1)
newapp.Start = '2020-09-25 08:00'
newapp.Subject = 'Testentry'
newapp.Duration = 15
newapp.Save()
```

throwing error: AttributeError:< unknown >.CreateItem.

I am calling the object 'subcalendar' with the Method CreateItem and the correct object type...seems I am blind but do not see the solution.
Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
newapp = calendar.Items.Add()
newapp.Start = '2020-09-25 08:00'
newapp.Subject = 'Testentry'
newapp.Duration = 15
newapp.Save()
```

The [Items.Add method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.add) creates a new Outlook item in the `Items` collection for the folder. If the type is not specified, the `Type` property of the Outlook item defaults to the type of the folder or to `MailItem` if the parent folder is not typed.

You may find the [How To: Create a new Outlook Appointment item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/outlook-create-appointment-item/) article helpful.